# Mapping set operations in python

Tags: python, set, mapping, operator-keyword

I have a very simple problem, but today, I confess I have trouble finding the solution:
I want to use the '&' operator on python sets, but I don't know how many sets I will have to deal with.
Is it possible to use a mapping with python to achieve this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

```
set.intersection(*some_list_of_sets)
```

If you still want to use the operator,

```
functools.reduce(operator.and_, some_list_of_sets)
```

Comment: Ok thanks it's working ! I am not well awake today !